# On merging, Is there a way to show diffs between working tree and stage 2/3 of index respectivly?

Tags: git

During a merge where conflicts is involved, (if I understand this correctly) for files labeled "both modified" by `git status`,
we can display diffs between working tree and stage 0/2/3 of index combined via

```
git diff -c
```

where (quoting from `gitrevisions(7)`)

> During a merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target
>   branch’s version (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the
>   version from the branch which is being merged.

But how do we display diffs between working tree and either side of merge (not both)?
In other words, if there is a file `A.txt` labeled "both modified", how can we display the differences between the working-tree version and stage-2 version (or stage-3 version) of it (but not both of it)?

Comment: Do you really need this at all?  The conflict markers will clearly show you both versions of modifications to the file.  If you have a Git merge tool, it gets even better, because you will see the original file in the center, and each modification on either side.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, now I'm dealing with a merge conflict that is just too messy in the combined diff, so I thought it would be cleaner if I can read diffs of either sides separately. As to GUI merge tool, that would be an option, but I'm using gnome-terminal and plain git diff commands for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff :2:path path
git diff :3:path path
```

This syntax is documented in [`man git-rev-parse`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html):

> #### *:<n>:<path>*, e.g. *:0:README*, *:README*
>
> A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a
> colon, followed by a path, names a blob object in the index at the
> given path. A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it)
> names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1 is the common
> ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version (typically the
> current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the branch which
> is being merged.

Comment: I actually tried this syntax. However what I did is `git diff path :2:path` which throws at me `fatal: :2:path: no such path in the working tree.` error. Looks like I have to put index entry before working tree copy, as you did.

Comment: @Naitree You can use `git diff -R` to output the reverse diff, if your prefer that order.